# Управление числительных и их сочетание с существительными

Tags: числительные, управление, количественно-именное-сочетание

Какой из трех вариантов будет правильным? Или возможны несколько вариантов?

1. Выпущенными государством ста миллионами автоматов возможно уничтожить, как водородными бомбами, все население земного шара.
2. Выпущенными государством сотней миллионов автоматов возможно уничтожить, как водородными бомбами, все население земного шара.
3. Выпущенной государством сотней миллионов автоматов возможно уничтожить, как водородными бомбами, все население земного шара.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте ограничимся ста автоматами, не против? Остальнаая часть фразы только путает.

1. Этими ста автоматами...
2. Этими сотней автоматов...
3. Этой сотней автоматов...

Первый вариант безусловно верен. Значит верен и исходный - с заменой паденжа у "автоматов".
Второй явно ошибочен. 
Что касается третьего, то тут можно спорить о значении слова "сотня". Если подразумевается примерное значение, т.е. существительное, то возможно. Хотя у нас тут еще и миллионы, так что подобный выбор вызывает сомнения.

Итак.
1. - верно
2. - неверно
3. - сомнительно, зависит от значения слова "сотня". Если это существительное (в значении "примерно сто" или "очень много"), то возможно. Если это числительное (100 000 000), то неправильно. По контексту - именно неправильно.

Comment: Если сказать "этими ста автоматами", то это конечно будет верно, но там говорится именно о ста миллионах автоматов, значит, "выпущенными государством ста миллионами автоматов" - правильно. Второй вариант, как я уже теперь вижу, действительно ошибочен. Третий, хотя и более гладкий, но числительное "сотня" как будто принижает и  искажает смысл фразы, ведь в действительности их там намного больше. Спасибо вам за развернутый ответ.

Comment: Так грамматика числительного та же. За исключением того, что "ста автомат**ами**" , но "ста миллионами автомат**ов**". Все согласования и управления за пределами этой конструкции одинаковы. У нас вопрос о согласовании со "ста", "сотней", а не с миллионами или автоматами. Так что мое упрощение вполне корректно. Но если это трудно понять, оставьте с "миллионами". Все выводы те же самые. Первое - верно, третье - грамматически возможно, но сомнительно. Второе неврено в любом случае.

Answer (score 4):

Мне больше нравится третий вариант: Выпущенной государством сотней миллионов автоматов возможно уничтожить, как водородными бомбами, все население земного шара.

Дело в том, что грамматически верный первый вариант предполагает точное исчисление, в то время как третий в большей степени выражает порядок указанного количества, что больше соответствует содержанию текста.

Примечание

Сотня - это существительное ж.рода, в состав числительных входить не может. Сто миллионов - это количественное числительное, сотня миллионов - это сочетание с количественным значением.